# JOIN across multi-query

Tags: mysql, join, multi-query

If I have a multi-query like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_database.`table` AS one
   WHERE one.some_field LIKE 'abc';
SELECT * FROM my_database.`table` AS two
    JOIN one
        ON one.id = two.relatedId;
```

Yes. Those are the same tables, and they are supposed to be. And of course, it's much more complex, but this example gets the point across.

Then I get an error (using PHP and PDO) like:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'my_database.one' doesn't exist

And I can circumvent this error by doing:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE one AS
    (SELECT * FROM table AS one);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE two AS
    (SELECT * FROM table AS two
        JOIN one 
            ON one.id = two.relatedId
    );
SELECT * FROM one;
SELECT * FROM two;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE one;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE two;
```

I tried using UNION between the first query and the second query, making it a single query, but got the same error. And I don't want to use a UNION anyway.

Is there another way to do this that doesn't require explicitly creating temporary tables in the process?

Note: `JOIN`ing on sub-queries isn't really acceptable, since then I'd have to write the same query twice, once for selecting it, and once for joining it.

**EDIT:** I want the result from both of the queries. And the 2nd query needs to JOIN on the result set from the first query.

Comment: Why not just use ` my_database.table AS one` in the `from` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do and you said JOINing on sub-queries wasn't acceptable but I'm afraid I don't understand the context but what about this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM my_database.`table`
        WHERE some_field LIKE 'abc'
    ) AS `one`
    my_database.`table` AS two
WHERE
    one.id = two.relatedId;
```

There may be a more elegant solution for your specific problem but without more details it's hard to say.

As Gordon stated in the comments above you can also simply join the table twice without using a subquery and put the criteria for both tables in the where clause but again without more context I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    my_database.`table` AS `one`,
    my_database.`table` AS two
WHERE
    one.some_field LIKE 'abc'
    AND one.id = two.relatedId;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Where you must specify the Table (one or two)

```
SELECT one.*,two.* FROM my_database.`table`  one
  LEFT JOIN  my_database.`table` two
    ON one.id = two.relatedId
  WHERE one.some_field LIKE 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to get result you need is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_database.`table` two
    JOIN (
       SELECT * 
       FROM my_database.`table` 
       WHERE one.some_field LIKE 'abc';
    ) one
        ON one.id = two.relatedId
```

But it seems to me very weird. What is your real goal and why?